# How to clear all react-native cache on Windows, and where are the files?

Tags: react-native, caching

I found this folder: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\metro-cache
Could i delete it ?
Is there another react-native cache folder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try below command to clear cache of npm packager from window.

```
del %appdata%\Temp\react-native-* & cd android & gradlew clean & cd .. & del node_modules/ & npm cache clean --force & npm install & npm start -- --reset-cache
```

[Check here,](https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d)

hope this will work for you :)

Comment: there's no folder react-native-* in my %appdata%\Temp (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Temp), and metro-cache folder is in AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: @Hardik Virani Thanks